# Subdomain folder path repeated Subdomain/Subdomain/index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mobile, subdomain

I have created a subdomain for my mobile site as as m.domain.com with a folder as /mobile. I am facing a directory config issue, as when I open m.domain.com, it's showing me 404 not found error with path mobile/mobile/index.html not found. I am using two different .htaccess files for root as well as mobile folder. When I remove one .htaccess file from mobile folder. It's opening a index page perfectly but other menus are giving path of m.rxcues.com/mobile/menu.html means mobile/mobile/menu.html with 404 error. I need a help with htacces on how to configure it perfectly?

Below is the htaccess file for root

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^/admin - [L,NC]

RewriteRule index.html templateouter.php
RewriteRule index.php templateouter.php
RewriteRule error.html error.php

#RewriteRule portfolio-([a-z0-9\-]+).html$ portfolio.php?pctid=$1

#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/?$ template.php?url=$1.html&module=$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^(gallery|hire|quote|pages|staff)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ template.php?page=$2&module=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(quote|hire)/?$ template.php?page=$1&module=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ template.php?url=$1.html

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/place-(.*) template.php?url=$1.html&place=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/(.*)/search-(.*) template.php?url=$1.html&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) template.php?url=$1.html&id=$2&name=$3&other_name=$4 [QSA,L]
```

And here is the htaccess file for mobile folder

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/mobile - [L,NC]

RewriteRule index.html template.php
RewriteRule index.php template.php
RewriteRule error.html error.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [L]


#RewriteRule portfolio-([a-z0-9\-]+).html$ portfolio.php?pctid=$1

#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/?$ template.php?url=$1.html&module=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(gallery|hire|quote|pages|staff)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ template.php?page=$2&module=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(quote|hire)/?$ template.php?page=$1&module=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ template.php?url=$1.html

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/place-(.*) template.php?url=$1.html&place=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/(.*)/search-(.*) template.php?url=$1.html&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) template.php?url=$1.html&id=$2&name=$3&other_name=$4 [QSA,L]
```

I really appreciate help..!!

Comment: Edit your question and place both .htaccess

Comment: I am just using the same htaccess file as the mobile site have just design change. I don't know much about htaccess modification. Any help will help me a lot

Comment: I have hosted my site & subdomain on linux hosted server, I haven't defined virtualhost in both the sites, as i am literally unaware of these server settings and all. Please bear with me to fix this in a proper way. I have defined $filepath $siteurl $baseurl and all in config file

Comment: Finally i hv resolved the issue, I hv just added Rewritebase / in mobile htaccess and its working like a charm, thanks anubhava for ur time & inputs